# Jenkins CI/CD debuggers and console logs not working

Tags: angular, angularjs, jenkins, cicd

I am working on hybrid angular application using angular 1.x and angular 8. I have come across a problem in which the code is hitting breakpoints (debugger) and showing console logs in developer tools in browser but only in **local environment (localhost)** but debuggers and console logs are not working in **staging/production environment**.

I have searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find the solution as this is causing lot of problem when debugging because i have to add alert to check the part of code as debuggers and console logs are not working in staging/production environment.

**The application is deployed using Jenkins CI/CD**

Any solution/idea to fix this problem will be of great help.....

Comment: I'm not sure how it is related to Jenkins (at least without a Jenkinsfile example).

Comment: Alexander Pletnev: I don't have access to Jenkinsfile as I am into frontend development. I would like to know is this problem related to frontend or related to some backend server configuration which is not allowing debuggers and console log to work in stage/production environment?

Comment: I believe it's better to check with your colleagues within the organization then.